# Qual é a diferença entre "String(1)" e "new String(1)" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, característica-linguagem

Por que em JavaScript é possível chamar `String` como função e também instanciando?

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var str1 = new String(1)
var str2 = String(1)

console.log("Valor é %s e o tipo é %s", str1, typeof(str1));
console.log("Valor é %s e o tipo é %s", str2, typeof(str2));
```

Notei que  existe uma pequena diferença entre um e outro, e isso me confundiu um pouco.

No primeiro resultado `new String` é dado como `object` por `typeof`. E `String()` é dado como `string`.

Mas na prática, existe diferença entre os dois? Pois percebo que eles também têm os mesmos métodos.

Veja:

```js
var a = new String(1);
var b = String(2);

console.log(a.concat);
console.log(b.concat);

console.log(a.substr);
console.log(b.substr);
```

**Observação**: Não precisamos focar apenas em `String`, já que o mesmo ocorre com as chamadas de `Number`, `Boolean` e `Array`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os *tipos primitivos* em JavaScript permitem converter algo em *valor primitivo* ou num objeto usando `new` para criar uma nova instância do *tipo primitivo*. Aparentemente são iguais pois podemos fazer:

```
String(1) == new String(1) // que dá true
```

Mas neste caso o que acontece é uma conversão entre tipos e no final de alguns passos internos a comparação fica `"1" == "1"`. Porém fazendo a comparação com `===`, que compara os *tipos* também:

```
String(1) === new String(1) // dá false!
```

pois na verdade `String(1)` dá um primitivo do tipo *String* e `new String(1)` dá um objeto, uma instância, que quando lhe pedimos o seu valor retorna um primitivo.

Ou seja:

```
String(1) === new String(1).valueOf() // true
```

Para o exemplo é indiferente se passamos numeros ou texto, ambos são convertidos para *string*, assim vou usar um exemplo para explicar melhor:

```js
const texto = 'Olá!';
const TypeString = String(texto);
const StringInstance = new String(texto);
console.log(typeof TypeString, typeof StringInstance); // string, object
console.log(TypeString, StringInstance); // Olá!, String {0: "O", 1: "l", 2: "á", 3: "!", length: 4, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "Olá!"}

TypeString.autor = 'Maria';
StringInstance.autor = 'Maria';
console.log(TypeString.autor, StringInstance.autor); // undefined, "Maria"
```

No exemplo em cima podemos ver mais diferênças. Uma delas é que um *tipo primitivo*, ou seja uma *string* de texto não pode ter mais propriedades, `TypeString.autor` não guarda nada. Porém uma intância, uma vez que é um objeto pode, e aí `StringInstance.autor = 'Maria';` fica guardado no `objeto`.

Este comportamento é o mesmo para *primitivos*, ou seja `Number`, `Boolean`, `String`.

Comment: Seria o mesmo caso do `int` e `Integer` no Java

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert exatamente isso.

Comment: Os primitivos não têm propriedades mas fingem que têm métodos: `console.log(TypeString.replace('á', 'é')); // olé`

Answer (score 8):

Uma diferença básica é que o `String(1)` funciona como tipo por valor e o `new String(1)` funciona como um tipo por referência, já que é um objeto. Isso dá diferença, porque se você tem duas *strings* de mesmo valor, elas são iguais, mas tem tem dois objetos que por acaso possuem o mesmo valor, eles são diferentes.

Em JavaScript `Strings` não são objetos, é um tipo primitivo, mas elas podem ser convertidos para objetos quando precisam e aí os métodos do protótipo adequado podem ser acessados.

A recomendação geral é usar apenas `String`.

```js
console.log(new String(1) === new String(1));
console.log(String(1) === String(1));
console.log("1" === "1");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Differences.js).